# Can't install apache Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg

I am having trouble installing apache2.
This is my output when I try to install it:

````
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-data apache2-utils
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/339 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1819 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 196569 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/apache2/error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var', which is also in package ea-apache24 2.4.51-1+2.1.cpanel
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-utils_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ab', which is also in package ea-apache24-tools 2.4.51-1+2.1.cpanel
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/apachectl', which is also in package ea-apache24 2.4.51-1+2.1.cpanel
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-utils_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

I tried deleting those files in the /var/cache/apt/archives/ but I kept getting the same errors.
````

Comment: What command(s) are you using?  Was a different version of apache already installed?

Comment: Your output clearly says: *Error processing package A. Trying to overwrite file F, which is also in package B*. A and B conflict, and B is already installed. Either uninstall B (usually the smart choice), or else use apt's --force option to keep both packages.

Comment: I cannot find the package B. I tried using ```find -iname *.cpanel```